# Could we stop adding comments to moderator elections to the comment queue on SO?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, moderator-election

**Steps to reproduce:**

- go to [Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) site and add a comment to a candidate
- go to your [comment section on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8041231/victoria?tab=activity&sort=comments) (that one is mine, I can't remember the trick to link Your user) and check the comments

**Problem:**

You'll see the comment from the [Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) site listed there.

Comment: You could argue that they should be visible on your profile, I'm impartial about that but if they are shown, at least make them clickable so you can see the comment in its context.

Comment: @rene, that's what you cannot. There's no link back to your Moderator Election comment.

Comment: The election pages are special and don't fit the normal Q+A framework.  So the dbase can't store the proper post number, so it cannot provide you with a link to click.  Meh, no biggie.

Comment: I see the comment, but what’s the problem?

Comment: @Clive, that you can see a comment put on there on SO would be fine for me. But there's not even a link to there.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying it’s a problem because you didn’t originally post the comment on SO proper (even though it’s on an election for SO), and you’d expect that to be on a different feed somewhere else or not at all? There not being a link seems like a separate problem if you don’t want it there in the first place

Comment: @Clive, adding a comment that appears on SO comment queue is weird by itself. That there is no link to such added comment is even more.

Comment: That’s what I don’t understand - what’s weird about a comment appearing in the comment list? Why wouldn’t it appear there? Is it just because it’s on an election you feel that way?

Comment: Nitpicking: That list isn't a "Queue". It s not lining up for anything.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a bug.

That activity list on your profile lists all your comments. That includes comments on nominations, by design.

Comment: Adding a link-back as with question/answer comments would be good.